# catkinize throws ValueError: Path is not a rosbuild stack

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello and happy new year!

I am trying to migrate some simple ROS packages (Fuerte) to Hydro and catkin.

As far as I understand the catkinize programm should be able to migrate packages from rosbuild to catkinize. But so far it has failed with two simple packages showing this traceback. According to http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild no special preperations, except for setting up the workspace should be required.

```
 catkinize sas_utils 1.0.0

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkinize", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('catkinize==0.1', 'catkinize')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 499, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1235, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkinize-0.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/catkinize", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkinize-0.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/catkinize", line 56, in main
    changeset = catkinize_stack(path, version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkinize-0.1-py2.7.egg/catkinize/main.py", line 79, in catkinize_stack
    path)
ValueError: Path is not a rosbuild stack, missing stack.xml at sas_utils
```

Why does it require a Sack as an input?

Furtermore I would like to know what the version number (the second input Parameter) is good for and when it becomes relevant.

Thats my OS specs:

- Linux Grot-M58p 3.8.0-34-generic #49~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 18:05:00 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

BR,

Mario

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114696/catkinize-throws-valueerror:-path-is-not-a-rosbuild-stack/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2014-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ticketed here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkinize/issues/38

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0